# how to get date and time in the format 2013-01-11 23:34:21?

Tags: c, unix

In my C program, how can I get the date and time in the format `2013-01-11 23:34:21`?

I tried

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
printf("%s", ctime(&now));
```

But it's giving it like `Fri Jan 11 23:50:33 2013`...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`strftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) function from `<time.h>`

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);

    struct tm* now_tm;
    now_tm = localtime(&now);

    char out[80];
    strftime (out, 80, "Now it's %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.", now_tm);

    puts(out);
}
```

Output

```
Now it's 2013-01-12 10:33:13.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) from `time.h`:

```
char timeString[20];
time_t t;
struct tm tmp;

t = time(NULL);

// TODO: Error checking if (t < 0)

tmp = localtime_r(&t, &tmp);

// TODO: Error checking if tmp == NULL

strftime(timeString, sizeof(timeString), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tmp));

// TODO: Error checking if returned number == sizeof(timeString)-1
```